# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized

Tags: java, hibernate, mysql-connector, tomcat9

I shifted from MS Windows to Ubuntu, then I try to run the project. I got an error when running the Tomcat 9 server. But on Windows, I could run the project without any issues. What have I missed here?

```
mysql --version
# mysql  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

1. error log

```
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:26 PM com.elephasvacation.tms.web.util.LogConfig initLogging
INFO: Logger initialized successfully...!
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:26 PM com.elephasvacation.tms.web.listener.MyContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: Context initialized successfully...!
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:26 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: TMS]
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:26 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:26 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tms?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true]
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=dhanusha, password=****}
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at com.elephasvacation.tms.web.util.HibernateUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory(HibernateUtil.java:57)
    at com.elephasvacation.tms.web.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:39)
    at com.elephasvacation.tms.web.listener.MyContextListener.contextInitialized(MyContextListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1783)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1049, SQLState: 42000
Nov 30, 2021 12:17:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown database 'tms'
```

2. application.properties

Following properties did work well before I shifted to Ubuntu. Is something wrong with mysql?

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
javax.persistence.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tms?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true
javax.persistence.jdbc.user=dhanusha
javax.persistence.jdbc.password=xxxx
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

3. persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="TMS">
      <description>
        Persistence unit for TMS database layer.
      </description>

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.elephasvacation.tms.web.entity.Customer</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

4. pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.elephasvacation.tms</groupId>
    <artifactId>tourism-management-system-backend-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>This project is developed as the backend service application for tourism management system.
    </description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- MySQL connector -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J for logging-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Yasson - JSONb-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse/yasson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Junit4 for unit testing -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Validator -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- lombok  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Apache Commons Codecs -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.20</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

5. HibernateUtil.java

```java
package com.elephasvacation.tms.web.util;

import com.elephasvacation.tms.web.commonConstant.HibernateConstant;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

/* JPA Bootstrapping and build EntityManagerFactory */
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = buildEntityManagerFactory();

    /** Expose the EntityManagerFactory instance.
    * @return EntityManagerFactory */
    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    /** Build the EntityManagerFactory.
     * @return EntityManagerFactory instance */
    private static EntityManagerFactory buildEntityManagerFactory() {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(HibernateUtil.class.getResourceAsStream(HibernateConstant.APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME)); // "/application.properties"

            entityManagerFactory = Persistence
                    .createEntityManagerFactory("TMS", properties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you noticed this? `ERROR: Unknown database 'tms'`

Comment: @UDS Yes, I did notice that. When I run the project, there is no MySQL database schema called 'tms'. I wanted to create that only if not exist. So that is why I used `application.properties` file `?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true` configuration. When I run this on Windows, `tms` database schema was created successfully if not exist. Now I explicitly created `tms` database schema using MySQL Workbench and then I tried to run the project. Project executed with no issues. I want to create the schema whenever only if not exist.

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason, guys. I made a mistake in the `application.properties` file.

Please note that you have to use `?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`. Without an `s`. Then, the project will run without any issue.

```
# corrected
javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tms?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Unknown database 'tms'

you can check to see if it does not database  'tms' exist.

Comment: I explicitly created the `tms` database schema using MySQL Workbench, then the project runs with no issues. But how can I create the `tms` database schema if only it does not exist? Please note that I have used `?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true` configuration in the `application.properties` file too.

Answer (score 1):

`createDatabaseIfNotExist` is not `createDatabaseIfNotExists`. There's an extra 's'.

[MySQL Official Document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-connection.html)